# $|\Phi(s)-\Phi(t)|\leq C(s-t)(\phi(s)s-\phi(t)t),\ s,t\geq 0$?

Tags: inequality

Let $p\in (1,\infty)$ and $s,t\geq 0$. Can I conclude that there exist a constant $C>0$ such that $$|s^p-t^p|\leq C(s-t)(s^{p-1}-t^{p-1})$$

More generally, suppose that $g(t)=\phi(t)t $ is an strictly increasing function defined for $t\geq 0$. Assume that $g\in C^1([0,\infty))$, $g(0)=0$ and $g(\infty)=\infty$. Define $\Phi(t)=\int_0^t \phi(s)sds$. Is true that there exist a constant $C>0$ such that

$$|\Phi(s)-\Phi(t)|\leq C(s-t)(\phi(s)s-\phi(t)t)$$

Remark 1: With those conditions, $\Phi$ is convex. Also we have that $\Phi(s)\leq \phi(s)s^2$ for $s\geq 0$. Maybe this can help for something.

I am in the moment stuck in this problem, so I cant give you any of my efforts.

Thank You.

Comment: Take $p=2$. Then for $s \neq t$ we have $\frac{|s^2-t^2|}{(s-t)^2} = \frac{|s+t|}{|s-t|}$, which is unbounded above near $s=t=1$.

Comment: @copper.hat, you are right, there is something worng with my calculations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NO. Note $s^p-t^p=(s-t)(s^{p-1}+s^{p-2}t+\dots+st^{p-2}+t^{p-1})$ for integer $p>1$.

You could ask for $s^p-t^p\le C(s-t)(s^{p-1}{\color{red}+}t^{p-1})$.